# How to hide the background icon in Expo-video-player

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, video-player

I am trying to hide the background circle when the video is playing `playIcon` and show it ONLY when the video is paused `pauseIcon`.

At the moment when the video is playing, I see a grey dot since the `pauseIcon` is `null` and when the video is paused I see the play icon. Any advice on how to remove the grey dot so no icon shows when video is playing?

```
<VideoPlayer
      videoProps={{
           isMuted: false,
           isLooping: true,
           shouldPlay: true,
           resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_COVER,
               source: {
                          uri: item.videoUri,
                        },
                          posterSource: item.posterUri,
                   }}
                          inFullscreen={true}
                          pauseIcon={() => null}
                          showControlsOnLoad={true}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNativeControls={false}`.
It's helps to hide the nativeIcons.